# Bootstrap Modal Appear Without Validation

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have a form in which I need to first validate the form then as I click book button a modal showing the confirmation message should appear
This is the button code:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-lg custom" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#book-modal"> BOOK </button>
```

However although I validated the input using "required" but it is not working and modal appear without entering any data

```
<input id="place" name="place" type="text" class="form-control my-size"  placeholder="Enter the place" maxlength="100" required>
```

Answer (score 0):

You actually have no link between your button and your text input, you may need for this a jquery function than is triggered on the change of the text input where it checks the input validity [(checkValidity)](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_validation_api.asp) and triggers the [modal](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#js-programmatic-api) window if the input is valid :

```
$("#place").change(function(){

   if($(this)[0].checkValidity()) // <<<< check for validity of the DOM element, thats why we use [0]
   {

      $('#book-modal').modal(); // if so run the modal window      
   } 
});
```

Comment: Its not working , still modal appear as i click the book button.I tried it after removing the data-toggle="modal" data-target="#book-modal" from button also, but it submit the form only. Then modal don't popup

Comment: I've posted here please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31749560/twitter-bootstrap-modal-appear-without-validation