# Twitter bootstrap modal appear without validation

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have a form in which I need to first validate the form then as I click book button a modal showing the confirmation message should appear.However although I validated the input using `required` but it is not working and modal appear without entering any data

```
<div class="zindex">
    <div class="row row-centered">
    <form name="getestimate_form" id="getestimate_form" action="#" method="post">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-5 col-centered form-group">
                <div id="imaginary_container"> 
                    <div class="input-group stylish-input-group">
                        <input id="pickup" type="text" class="form-control my-size" name="pickup" maxlength="100"  placeholder="PickUP" aria-required="true" required >
                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></span>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-5 col-centered form-group">
                <div id="imaginary_container"> 
                    <div class="input-group stylish-input-group">
                        <input id="dropoff" name="dropoff" type="text" class="form-control my-size"  placeholder="Drop Off" maxlength="100" required >
                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></span>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div> 
        </div>  
        <div class="row row-centered">        
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-lg custom " data-toggle="modal" data-target="#book-modal"> BOOK </button>      
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-lg custom"> QUOTES </a>
        </div>
    </form>
    </div>
    <!-- Searchbar end -->
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
</div>
```

JS

```
<script>
    $("#pickup").change(function(){ 
        if($(this)[0].checkValidity()) { 
            //check for validity of the DOM element, thats why we use [0] 
            $('#book-modal').modal(); // if so run the modal window 
        } 
    });
</script>
```

Comment: The required attribute handles behavior in the form. It doesn't control what a modal does. You'll need to write some jQuery to do that.

Comment: i wrote jquery as suggested by @KAD but not working  $("#pickup").change(function(){

   if($(this)[0].checkValidity()) // <<<< check for validity of the DOM element, thats why we use [0]
   {

      $('#book-modal').modal(); // if so run the modal window      
   } 
});

Comment: The reason it is appearing because input with `id=pickup` is inside hidden div